# IViewObjectPresentSite interface of mshtml

Tags: c#, mshtml

Does any one know how to use the IViewObjectPresentSite interface of mshtml (IE9).

I need to disable the hardware acceleration using the IsHardwareComposition method.

Kindly help

Regards,
James

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can disable it. IIRC IsHardwareComposition only returns if it is enabled; it does not enable you to enable or disable it. Maybe setCompositionMode is what you're searching for?

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I need to use the SetCompositionMode Method

Comment: Can you please advice me on how to do this using c#